# iOS: How to let UITableView draw its cells out of its bounds?

Tags: uitableview, ios7

I have a `UITableView` which has cells I want to be drawn outside of its own bounds. The reason I want this is because in IOS 7 the keyboard is translucent, so I want the contents of the tableview to be visible through the keyboard.

I succeeded accomplishing the same with a `UIScrollView`. I simply set `clipsToBounds` to `NO` and off I go!

I know why the same thing doesn't work with `UITableView`, because it uses a clever reusing of cells trick. This means that cells which scroll out of bounds at the top get moved to the bottom to be reused there (and vise versa).

So I think I want a way to tell `UITableView` to extend the array of visible cells or something. Does anyone have a clever trick to accomplish this?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't simply make the table bigger?

Comment: Yes, because then you would never be able to scroll to the bottom, because part of the table view would be behind the keyboard.

Comment: To show you what I mean: open Messages on iPad. Undock the keyboard and move it to the middle of the screen. Open a long conversation with someone. Scroll all the way up. You can see that the scroll view adjusted to the keyboard because it has resized. But still, if you scroll up you see the messages below the keyboard as well!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the best way to accomplish this is to simply make the table bigger and set the table's `contentInset` with enough bottom padding so that you can scroll the entire table into view.

I think this is precisely the sort of thing `contentInset` is intended for.

Comment: It works! My only problem is: the scrollbar isn't aligned properly now. I want the scrollbar only to be visible above the keyboard, not below the keyboard. Just like in the Messages app.

Comment: Oh I found the solution in the docs: I have to set the scrollIndicatorInsets as well. Perfect! Thank you!!